# How to search in SharePoint with C# + CAML

Tags: search, development

I am developing a search web part. I am confused about which technique I have to use.

Let's say I have a column in my Contact List called "Details", and one of the list items for this column contains a sentence like: "SharePoint Overflow is very good for SharePoint developers".

If i insert the keyword "Overflow" into the text box of the search web part then this particular record must be in the results out of all other records. That is, the search must check in the "Details" column.

What do I have to do?

Comment: why - voting, is any wrong question i am asking??

Comment: we receive some... questionable... questions once in a while by disgruntled (SharePoint?) developers that use this forum to discharge their loathing of SharePoint. I guess the question was mistaken for one of those (eg. your comment "this forum is very good to junk the sharepoint developers"), also the question wasnt entirely clear to me... 
If the question was sincere (and James havent already answered it), please rephrase the question :-)

Comment: This is your problem dear. I have gave just example of the sentence.I don't think so any mistake there...My question is too clear. I just want to get highlighted the keywords though they are from description. that's is. Why you can't understand my question please mention it.

Comment: I've now rewritten this question. @Lalit Sharepoint: Please be careful of your wording in future.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post over on StackOverflow may answer your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870314/sharepoint-list-caml-query-using-contains

Comment: hi james, someone suggest me for this URL , so I just put this question here....Thanks for reply

Comment: The solution in the URL appears to satisfy your original requirement. What is it you require?